# pip fails to install all packages from requirements.txt

Tags: python, pip, dependencies, conda, requirements.txt

I created and maintain a package [seg-metrics](https://pypi.org/project/seg-metrics/). But I found that I can not install all of its dependencies when I use `pip install seg-metrics` to install it, even though I have already included all necessary dependencies into the [requirements.txt](https://github.com/Jingnan-Jia/segmentation_metrics/blob/dev/requirements.txt).

**Can you tell me why and how to solve it?**

You can try to reproduce it into your own pc.

1. conda create -n test_env python=3.8 pip  # install pip as well
2. pip install seg-metrics  # install the package
3. pip list  # shown the installed package, you can see seg-metrics, but you can not see the dependencies like: SimpleITK and medutils. This can be verified by the following commands.
4. python  # enter the python interpreter
5. import seg_metrics.seg_metrics as sm  # Error occured here !!!

Comment: `pip install seg-metrics` doesn't use `requirements.txt`. Why would it? You have to declare dependencies in `setup.py`; you can read `requirements.txt` in `setup.py`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @phd, I found that I should set `install_requires` in `setup.py`. After that, this issue was fixed.